# Link / DNS prefetching, drive by downloads and security - Firefox

Tags: firefox, security, links

When using Firefox with link and DNS pre-fetching, would it lead to a security risk in the following situation:

One visits a post with an embedded link, that leads to a website which tries to install apks on your pc and redirects to a lot of ads.

However, said link is not clicked.

Does link pre-fetching (or DNS prefetching) open up the possibility of experiencing "drive-by" downloads without having connected to the website per se?

Answer (score 1):

Link prefetching is sometimes mentioned as a security menace, but opinions vary.

For example, the Computer Emergency Response Team in the article
[DNS prefetching in web browsers](https://www.cert-ist.com/public/en/SO_detail?code=dns_prefetching)
writes this:

> prefetching a web page in the background could eventually cause a user system to be infected by a malware (drive-by download attack), if this prefetched page contained a malicious code. In this given situation, the web browser of the victim would be compromised in a completely invisible way, since the user has not clicked on a particular link when the infection occurs.

I must say that this seems very far-fetched, because:

- Prefetch will not download any files except HTML files, and certainly not without
  advising the user
- Prefetch will not execute JavaScript on the downloaded HTML pages unless the link
  was clicked by the user.
- Prefetch is only one level, in the sense that links on the prefetched pages are
  not recursively prefetched in turn.

For these reasons, I don't see a danger in prefetch.
JavaScript included in the main and included pages is much more dangerous.